# Fetch and download under same root

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have this route **payments/transactions** which fetches all the data. What I would like to do is get a CSV file without adding any new routes or query params so my route would look like **payments/transactions.csv** and send response based on the mime type. Im using NODEJS and EXPRESS. Thank you very much for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify your route like this:

```
app.get("/payment/transactions(:extension?)", function...
```

This adds an optional parameter to your route, that you can check with `req.params.extension`.

---

A side note: I would prefer to check the `req.accepts` property to see which type the client requests. See http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.accepts